# SingleConnectionFactory - raises ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: spring, spring-jms

I use multiple SimpleMessageListenerContainers and they all use the SAME connection from a SingleConnectionFactory.  They are all registered in the SingleConnectionFactory's AggregatedExceptionListener.  Because, when the SingleConnectionFactory's JMS Connection is disconnected, all the SMLCs need to be informed to clear their Sessions and Consumers and go get the new Connection from the SCF.

However, this error occurs while the SingleConnectionFactory's AggregatedExceptionListener iterates over its "this.delegates" and attempts to invoke "listener.onException()" (eg. all my SMLCs are the delegates).

It would appear a bug in the Spring class.  It should perhaps, make a copy of the delegates and then iterate over the copied list, so if the list is modified, it doesn't raise a ConcurrentModificationException.

Any thoughts on a work around are appreciated.

```
13:30:28,201 ERROR [SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Encountered non-recoverable JMSException
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1998)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:2017)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onException(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:314)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:200)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.activemq.openwire.OpenWireFormat.unmarshal(OpenWireFormat.java:258)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:221)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:213)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:196)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "ActiveMQ Connection Executor: tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:9002@58017" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$AggregatedExceptionListener.onException(SingleConnectionFactory.java:670)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection$5.run(ActiveMQConnection.java:2005)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug as you suspected, see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13421.

It should be fixed in the upcoming versions 4.1.8 and 4.2.2, scheduled for release at October 15, 2015.